# Fluidity: Convex or level

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, surface-tension

So I'm debunking a flat Earth article [here](http://earthisnotaglobe.com/) and I came across a false proof stating that "If the Earth was round, fluids such as water would have a convex surface that matches the roundness of the earth." 
Now, I'm going to go against my common sense's words here because the debunking statement I came up with is that the Earth is so large that water just appears to be level when it is actually convex at a microscopic level, but that's probably wrong. How does water appear level even though the Earth is round? I haven't received that much education, so this may be a strange question. But can someone tell me whether that is right or wrong, please?

Comment: It's actually convex at the macroscopic scale (on the order of hundreds of miles) rather than the microscopic scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct except for 'at the microscopic level.' The amount of curvature starts off at a few inches per mile and grows rapidly with distance from a given reference point. Not microscopic, but still [challenging to measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedford_Level_experiment).